# como estilizo o H1 com uma imagem

Tags: html, css

estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um `h1` e preciso colocar uma imagem nele, ai a imagem original de 833 x 56, bom eu coloquei direto pelo `h1` com o seguinte código `<img src="images/h1.png"/>`, funcionou porém eu não poderia colocar um texto sobre ela, a não ser que eu ja colocasse o texto junto a imagem, e não é isso que eu desejo, ai eu fiz outro código que é o seguinte porém não tive sucesso, a intenção com esse código era ficar assim !https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBAIm.png porém ficou assim !https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCgQe.png oque estou fazendo de errado ?

```
<div id="left">
            <h1>séries</h1>
            <div class="center_left"></div>
        </div>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 833px;
    height: 56px;
z-index: 9999;
    background: url(../images/h1.png) no-repeat;
}
#left {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 20px 0 0;
            width: 833px;
        }
.center_left {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 703px;
            height: 700px;
            border: 15px solid #d4d4d4;
            background-color: #ebebeb;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Deve ser outro elemento HTML na pagina que esta cobrindo a sua imagem, no teste que fiz o seu código esta normal, de detalhes.

Comment: garanto que não tem, porque ja fiz esse teste, diminui o tamanho da imagem e deu a mesma coisa, ´também coloquei o z-index: 9999

Comment: olha a pergunta acima, o código é aquele, e garanto que não tem nada "em cima da imagem" porque ela esta com `position:absolute` e `z-index:9999`

Comment: vou editar a pergunta com mais detalhes de códigos

Comment: testei aqui e funcionou também, engraçado no meu site não funciona, enfim vou refazer meu site todo, porque aparentemente não consigo detectar o problema!

Comment: como assim mais detalhes ? posso te passar o link do meu site ai você ve o código fonte ?

Comment: Tb testei e funcionou normal. Vc está usando algum Normalizer ou Reset css? Ou está incluindo algum outro .CSS? Pelo Developer tool do Chrome tem que vc ver quais estilos estão afetando o seu elemento pela Aba  Computer

Comment: então hugo, meu reset é o seguinte `margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: box-sizing;` e css outros css eu puxo dois que são do awesomefonts, mais creio que isso não esteja afetando

Comment: Pode ser o link do seu site ou criar um exemplo no jsfiddle que cause o erro idêntico ao do seu site também serviria.

Comment: o link é este Guilherme Nascimento http://www.scrashfilmes.rf.gd/

Comment: Mayron no Firefox e no Chrome carregaram normalmente

Comment: consegui resolver amigo, eu usava o chrome beta, ai mudei deu certinho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do autor era um BUG no Chrome **Beta**, como ele mesmo [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261502/como-estilizo-o-h1-com-uma-imagem/261541#comment536130_261502):

> consegui resolver amigo, eu usava o chrome beta, ai mudei deu certinho

A imagem em outros navegadores funcionava perfeitamente, mas no **Chrome Beta** ficava assim:

[image: chrome beta]

Logo era um problema na **versão do navegador** mesmo e **não** no código.